# jquery callback calls before animation completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to empty a div after the slideUp but it gets empty before sliding up completely . here is my code . The data i need to clear is being taken through Ajax. Here is the complete code

```
        $('.more').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var fd = $(this).attr('id');
                    var data = 'fd='+ fd ;

                    if($('#e_' + fd).is(':visible')){
                      $('#e_' + fd).slideUp(300, function() {
                            $('#e_' + fd).empty();

                        });

                        }
                    else{


    $('#e_' + fd).empty().append('<div class="load"></div>').slideDown(300); // for ajax loader


                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "file.php",
                        data: data,

                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html)
                        {

                        $('#e_' + fd).empty().append(html).slideDown(800);

                          }
                         });

                      return false; }
                });
```

Same problem occurs with the ajax loader. infact it is not loading either.

Comment: Suggestion: http://jsbeautifier.org Consistent, clear code indentation and brace location makes code *dramatically* easier to read, maintain, and debug. Doing things higgledy-piggledy *will* cost you time and hassle, and makes it hard for people to help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty) isn't part of the animation suite and so it doesn't use the animation queue. By calling `empty` on the return value from `slideUp`, you're calling it *immediately* (the way you are with `next`, for instance, on the return value from `closest`). That's not a callback, that's just a chained call.

You have to use the callback option that [`slideUp`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp) provides:

```
$(this).closest(".feed").next(".feed_expand").slideUp(300, function() {
    $(this).empty();
});
```

Only functions in the [animation (effects) suite](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) know about and use the queue.

Here's an example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/oyidex/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/oyidex/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    .feed_expand {
      height: 10em;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .feed {
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="feed">
    <div class="clicker">Click me</div>
  </div>
  <div class="feed_expand">
    I'm the feed_expand, I have content
  </div>
  <script>
    $(".clicker").click(function() {
      $(this).closest(".feed").next(".feed_expand").slideUp(300, function() {
        $(this).empty();
      });

      // Show the expand again a second later
      var self = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(self).closest(".feed").next(".feed_expand").slideDown();
        $("<p>").html("As we can see, the content in feed_expand has been removed").appendTo(document.body);
      }, 1300);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it dont even empty the container

Comment: @user1223654: The above **does** work: http://jsbin.com/oyidex/1 (source: http://jsbin.com/oyidex/1/edit). So the problem lies elsewhere, in code you haven't shown. Look in the JavaScript console, and follow the code through step-by-step with the debugger (if your browser doesn't have one, switch to a more modern one that does).

Comment: i forgot to mention that the data i wana clear is loaded through ajax. is this of some effect ?

Comment: @user1223654: You'd have to show the HTML as well. Fundamentally, the element has to exist when you look up up with `$()`. If it does, then it will be found and emptied. The code you've shown handles clicks on elements and takes their ID and then acts on elements with that same ID with `e_` put at the front. So if the user clicks the element with `id="foo"`, you're acting on an element with `id="e_foo"`. Provided it exists, `$("#e_" + fd).empty()` will empty it.

Answer (score 0):

`.promise().done()` is your friend :)

```
$(this).closest(".feed").next(".feed_expand").slideUp(300).promise().done(function(){
  $(this).empty();
});
```

Comment: `slideUp` *already* provides a callback, you don't need to jump through hoops to get one.

Comment: um... yeah :) I've just gotten lazy after using this method to many times-

Comment: This is the order: 1) On click ->load data->slide down 2. slide->up -> remove content. In both cases you hav to use the **callback** or the promise().done() functions.